# Potential visibility issue between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm relatively new to Java so you'll have to excuse my ignorance.

I'm running a ScheduledExecutorService with 2 threads. One is for consuming something and one is for producing some items. I'm mainly interested in the producer at this particular moment.

I have another class that's used as an orchestrator to manage the producer and consumer.

```
public final class PublicStashTabsOrchestrator {
    // properties, constructor, etc...

    PublicStashTabsProducer publicStashTabsProducer = new PublicStashTabsProducer ();
    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(publicStashTabsProducer , 1000, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

In the Producer I'm calling a paginated API. The next page is in a key called "next_request_id", so each request will be used to call the next request and so on.

I'm doing some work with the response but most importantly I'm setting the "next_request_id" in a BlockingQueue(which is really not necessary but for the purposes of this question I used this).

```
public class PublicStashTabsProducer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> nextIdQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call api get next_request_id
        nextIdQueue.put(nextIdFromRequest);
    }
}
```

Lets assume that the 2 threads are called Thread1 and Thread2 for simplicity sake.

**Is what I'm doing prone to visibility issue between threads?**

Here's what scenario I tested(and it worked fine, but I'm not convinced).

Executor service starts schedule -> Thread1 is chosen -> calls API -> puts "next_request_id" in nextIdQueue -> exit runnable

Executor service starts schedule -> Thread2 is chosen -> can thread 2 see an empty nextIdQueue even though Thread1 added a value in?

Also bonus question, what I'm doing seems wasteful. each `scheduleWithFixedDelay` call will just consume resources. Would it be unwise to do a `while(!nextIdQueue.isEmpty()) {...}` since this will work indefinitely...?

Comment: `ArrayBlockingQueue` is thread safe according to doc, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely safe, `ArrayBlockingQueue` is thread-safe.

Typical approach for infinite queue reading is

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    nextIdQueue.take()
}
```

Method `take()` blocks until an element becomes available and returns it immediately upon appearance.

Comment: In this context it seems very similar to `while(!nextIdQueue.isEmpty()) {...}`. Why should I avoid doing this over what you suggested? Is `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` better in some way?

Comment: Are you going to execute this somewhere outside `PublicStashTabsProducer` task? With just `while(!nextIdQueue.isEmpty())` your queue consumption wouldn't be infinite since it won't wait for new id's to come

Comment: Nop, only inside `PublicStashTabsProducer`. No other class will touch that queue.

Comment: Then how would you call any of these read loops? If you schedule `PublicStashTabsProducer` to the executor, then its `run` which does put-s would be performed

Comment: I just realized I didn't post the whole code...sorry about that. So what the `run()` method will do is: read from queue -> do request -> get next_id from queue -> put next_id in queue. So a while would make sense here. Not to mention I'd just keep the same thread running without wasting resources.